# Strange output of FFT in python (scipy)

Tags: python, audio, numpy, scipy, fft

I'm using the `scipy` module with Python 2.7 to analyse some WAV files.

It works properly, but I can't understand why a simple sine wave as input doesn't give as output a single point (the correct spectrum), but instead a strange curve.

This is an example

[image]

Comment: Can you provide what code you were using? Without more information it may be difficult or impossible to help you.

Comment: This is not a Stack Overflow question. The frequency of your sine curve does not lie in the centre of a spectral bin in the Fourier domain. Therefore you get spectral bleeding into the rest of the Fourier bins.

Comment: @ebarr: I think it is a valid question for SO once some code is added.  And you have already answered it as well. :)

Comment: @ebarr It looks like you are referring to [spectral leakage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) (figure 1)? This does not look like spectral leakage, because the side lobes are not present. This happens because the sampling interval is quite far from a multiple of the main period. user3640373, consider applying a window function first, or changing your sampling interval length.

Comment: @flebool This looks exactly like spectral leakage. The OP is plotting one value per DFT bin. Go back and look at the picture in the link you posted and you will see that if the central value of each DFT bin is plotted you would get exactly what the OP shows.

Comment: @ebarr I see your point. However, from the wikipedia page "the figure depicts a case where the actual frequency of the sinusoid happens to coincide with a DFT sample" and then "When it misses the maximum value by some amount (up to 1/2 bin), the measurement error is referred to as scalloping loss". Likely in this case the actual frequency is really close to a DFT bin, so that the value of each DFT bin is close to the maximum and we do not see the zeros, and then we do not see the scallops. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: The LSB of 16-bit PCM has a signal power of about -90dB, so if this is what you're using, the noise floor isn't going to be any lower than that. 
If using single precision floating point, you can probably looking at a noise floor about ~-138db. It's not hard to imagine a bunch of normalisations in calculating the FFT increasing this somewhat.

However, as others have pointed out, the FFT can effectively be seen as a bunch of band-pass filters.  In the stop-bands, the filter gain approaches zero towards infinity in each direction, but is definitely not zero near the peak.